# Download iOS 6 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, simulator

I have xcode 4.5.2 installed. I want to test my app in iOS 6. I went to `Xcode/Preferences/Downloads`, but I don't see iOS 6 simulator in the list. How should I download it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not already there? XCode 4.5.x normally already includes the iOS6 SDK.

Comment: IOS 6 sdk is there. How Can i create IOS 6  simulator from that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 4.5.2 should come with iOS 6 simulator. But if not:

Where it says the simulator version (the tab next to the name of your app next to 'Run' and 'Stop') click it and scroll down and press 'More Simulators' where you have the option to install more simulators. Is iOS 6 simulator there?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed all of my iOS 7 woes regarding not having an iOS 6 simulator

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4.5.2 comes with the iOS 6 SDK, so you're automatically testing with iOS 6 when you launch your app in the simulator.

Unless you download the iOS 5 simulator in the Xcode download pane and set the simulator to be testing in an iOS 5 environment.